# Aligning boxes horizontally

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I created these 3 boxes:

[image]

in my WordPress site but I'm having a heck of a time aligning them.

This is how the back-end is looking:

```
[one_fourth boxed="true" centered_text="true" animation="Fade In From Bottom" delay="0" style = "opacity: 1; bottom: 0px;"]

<h3><font color ="000000">Get Daily Motivation</font></h3>

<div class="fb-like" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/Medically-Supervised-Fitness-538796346231284/?fref=ts" data-layout="standard" data-action="like" data-show-faces="false" data-share="false"></div>[/one_fourth]

[one_fourth boxed="true" centered_text="true" animation="Fade In From Bottom" delay="0" style = "opacity: 1; bottom: 0px;"]

<h3><font color = "000000">Watch MSF Channel</font></h3>

<div class="g-ytsubscribe" data-channel="MedSupervisedFitness" data-layout="default" data-count="default"></div>[/one_fourth]

[one_fourth_last boxed="true" centered_text="true" animation="Fade In From Bottom" delay="0" style = "opacity: 1; bottom: 0px;"]

<h3><font color = "000000">Follow Us on Instagram</font></h3>

}

<span class="ig-follow" data-id="522d6eb32d" data-handle="a_littlebit_of_fashion" data-count="false" data-size="small" data-username="false"></span>[/one_fourth_last]
```

Answer (score 0):

There are line breaks (`<br>`) between those boxes. WordPress automatically generates them from new lines in the code you provided. Your code should look like this:

```
[one_fourth boxed="true" centered_text="true" animation="Fade In From Bottom" delay="0" style = "opacity: 1; bottom: 0px;"]<h3><font color ="000000">Get Daily Motivation</font></h3><div class="fb-like" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/Medically-Supervised-Fitness-538796346231284/?fref=ts" data-layout="standard" data-action="like" data-show-faces="false" data-share="false"></div>[/one_fourth][one_fourth boxed="true" centered_text="true" animation="Fade In From Bottom" delay="0" style = "opacity: 1; bottom: 0px;"]<h3><font color = "000000">Watch MSF Channel</font></h3><div class="g-ytsubscribe" data-channel="MedSupervisedFitness" data-layout="default" data-count="default"></div>[/one_fourth][one_fourth_last boxed="true" centered_text="true" animation="Fade In From Bottom" delay="0" style = "opacity: 1; bottom: 0px;"]<h3><font color = "000000">Follow Us on Instagram</font></h3><span class="ig-follow" data-id="522d6eb32d" data-handle="a_littlebit_of_fashion" data-count="false" data-size="small" data-username="false"></span>[/one_fourth_last]
```

Answer (score -1):

Remove breaktag between the blocks